# How to use array filter criteria agaist object in lodash?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, ecmascript-6, lodash

How to filter object ageist another object in lodash? but the criteria object is array..

```
var form = { type: ['xyz', 'abc'], name: 'pre-1' }

var items = [
 { type: 'xyz', name: 'pre-1' },
 { type: 'abc', name: 'pre-1' }, 
 { type: 'xyz', name: 'pre-2' }, 
]

const results = lodash.filter(items, form);
```

The `results` should be `xyz` and `abc`:

```
results = [{ type: 'xyz', name: 'pre-1' }, { type: 'abc', name: 'pre-1' }]
```

Is it something I can do using `filter` method?

Comment: what is your expected output? just ['xyz','abc']?

Comment: ^^ e.g., is that an OR or an AND. Also, what did you see when you looked at [the documentation](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11#filter)?

Comment: I just edit my question

Comment: In lodash documention they not say nothing about something like this

Answer (score 1):

Well, you can use custom filter method with lodash. Try below:

```js
var form = { type: ['xyz', 'abc'], name: 'pre-1' }

var items = [
 { type: 'xyz', name: 'pre-1' },
 { type: 'abc', name: 'pre-1' }, 
 { type: 'xyz', name: 'pre-2' }, 
]

let filtered = _.filter(items, (item)=>{
    return form.type.indexOf(item.type) >= 0 && form.name == item.name
});

console.log(filtered);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.11/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var form = { type: ['xyz', 'abc'], name: 'pre-1' }

var items = [
 { type: 'xyz', name: 'pre-1' },
 { type: 'abc', name: 'pre-1' }, 
 { type: 'xyz', name: 'pre-2' }, 
]

var item = _.filter(items, i => {
 return form.type.indexOf(i.type) > -1 && form.name === i.name
});

console.log(item)
```

Answer (score 0):

Check if `form.name === item.name`, and if so use [`Array.includes()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) to check if the `item.type` appears in `form.type`.

Note: I've used the vanilla JS filter and includes methods, but you can substitute them with lodash's `_.filter()` and [`_.includes()`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11#includes).

```js
const form = { type: ['xyz', 'abc'], name: 'pre-1' }

const items = [{"type":"xyz","name":"pre-1"},{"type":"abc","name":"pre-1"},{"type":"xyz","name":"pre-2"}]

const result = items.filter(item =>
  form.name === item.name && form.type.includes(item.type)
)

console.log(result)
```

Another option with lodash is to use [`_.intersectionWith()`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11#intersectionWith), and in the comperator function check if the item's name is identical to the form's name, and the type exists in the types.

```js
const form = { type: ['xyz', 'abc'], name: 'pre-1' }

const items = [{"type":"xyz","name":"pre-1"},{"type":"abc","name":"pre-1"},{"type":"xyz","name":"pre-2"}]

const result = _.intersectionWith(items, form.type, (item, type) =>
  form.name === item.name && item.type === type
)

console.log(result)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.11/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you `reduce` your items to an object map where items can be found by a combination of the `type` and `name` then it can be a simple map by `key` with or without lodash:

```js
var form = { type: ['xyz', 'abc'], name: 'pre-1' }

var items = [
 { type: 'xyz', name: 'pre-1' },
 { type: 'abc', name: 'pre-1' }, 
 { type: 'xyz', name: 'pre-2' }, 
].reduce((r,c) => (r[`${c.type}-${c.name}`] = c, r), {}) // convert to object map

let result = form.type.map(t => items[`${t}-${form.name}`]) // map by key

console.log(result)
```

With lodash you can use [`_.keyBy`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11#keyBy) and [`_.map`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11#map):

```js
var form = { type: ['xyz', 'abc'], name: 'pre-1' }

var items = _.keyBy([
 { type: 'xyz', name: 'pre-1' },
 { type: 'abc', name: 'pre-1' }, 
 { type: 'xyz', name: 'pre-2' }, 
], x => `${x.type}-${x.name}`)

let result = _.map(form.type, t => items[`${t}-${form.name}`])

console.log(result)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.11/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

This way from performance stand point you are in the `O(N)` territory.

Answer (score 0):

Simple in pure JS:

```js
var form = { type: ['xyz', 'abc'], name: 'pre-1' }

var items = [
 { type: 'xyz', name: 'pre-1' },
 { type: 'abc', name: 'pre-1' }, 
 { type: 'xyz', name: 'pre-2' }, 
]

const res = items.filter(({ type, name }) => form.type.includes(type) && form.name == name);

console.log(res);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: auto; }
```

If you really want to, you can use Lodash's [`_.filter`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11#filter) method like so:

```js
var form = { type: ['xyz', 'abc'], name: 'pre-1' }

var items = [
 { type: 'xyz', name: 'pre-1' },
 { type: 'abc', name: 'pre-1' }, 
 { type: 'xyz', name: 'pre-2' }, 
]

const res = _.filter(items, ({ type, name }) => form.type.includes(type) && form.name == name);

console.log(res);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: auto; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.11/lodash.js"></script>
```